# Mongo DB Make directory for the first time

Tags: mongodb

Before you start MongoDB for the first time, create the directory to which the mongod process will write data.
I typed this command in terminal

mkdir -p /data/db

but I got

mkdir: /data/db: Permission denied

also I tried to change the permission

chmod ugo+rwx /data/db

chmod: /data/db: No such file or directory

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You probably don't really want to do that. Which OS are you installing on?

Comment: macOS high Sierra version 10.13.4